# filling out missing values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

new to python and can't seem to find the exact answer I am looking for though 
I believe there is an easier way to fill this info

I have df1 and df2

```
df1: FirstName  LastName  PhNo  uniqueid

df2: uniqueid PhNo
```

I want to fill values missing in df1['PhNo'], with matching values in df2 based on matching uniqueid == uniqueid

Codes I used are as follows

```
dff = pd.merge(df1,df2,on = 'uniqueid', how = 'Left')
dff['PhNo'] = 0
dff['PhNo'][df1['PhNo_x'] >= 1] = df1['PhNo_x']
df1['PhNo'][df2['PhNo_y'] >= 1] = df1['PhNo_y']
```

this seems to do the work but does not seem like an efficient way of doing this.  I am looking for a less number of lines and better technique than merge

df1

```
FirstName  LastName  PhNo    uniqueid
Sam        R         123x    1
John       S         345x    2
Paul       K         np.Nan  3
Laney      P         no.NaN  4
```

df2

```
uniqueid  PhNo
1         213x
3         675x
4         987x
```

desired output: df1

```
FirstName  LastName  PhNo    uniqueid
Sam        R         123x    1
John       S         345x    2
Paul       K         **675x**    3
Laney      P         **987x**    4
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample, 4-5 rows with expected output?

Comment: i added the data sample as requested...

Comment: Thank you, so solution working nice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'FirstName':list('abcdef'),
        'LastName':list('aaabbb'),
         'PhNo':[7,np.nan,9,4,np.nan,np.nan],
         'uniqueid':[5,3,6,9,2,4],

})

print (df1)
  FirstName LastName  PhNo  uniqueid
0         a        a   7.0         5
1         b        a   NaN         3
2         c        a   9.0         6
3         d        b   4.0         9
4         e        b   NaN         2
5         f        b   NaN         4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
         'PhNo':[10,90,30,20],
         'uniqueid':[3,6,9,4],

})
print (df2)
   PhNo  uniqueid
0    10         3
1    90         6
2    30         9
3    20         4
```

---

```
s = df2.set_index('uniqueid')['PhNo']
df1['PhNo'] = df1['PhNo'].fillna(df1['uniqueid'].map(s))
print (df1)
  FirstName LastName  PhNo  uniqueid
0         a        a   7.0         5
1         b        a  10.0         3
2         c        a   9.0         6
3         d        b   4.0         9
4         e        b   NaN         2
5         f        b  20.0         4
```

Comment: @anky_91 - I ask for data for 100% verification :)

Comment: @jezrael I am getting 0 rather than the value from df2

Comment: @jezrael found the error, my database had "0" rather than empty string,    
 df1['PhNo'].replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True) did the trick though.  Would the similar solution work for "0" values or should i post it as separate question?

Comment: @Shri - With `0` is solution `df1['PhNo'] = np.where(df1['PhNo'] == 0, df1['uniqueid'].map(s), df1['PhNo'])`

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame.fillna(value= &n)